# Travis CI: error when installing rpy2

Tags: python, r, travis-ci, rpy2

I am developing a python package that depends on `rpy2`. I would like to run test with Travis CI. In `.travis.yml` I install conda and run tests with `green`:

```
language: python

# Be strict when checking our package
warnings_are_errors: true

# command to install dependencies
install:
  # http://conda.pydata.org/docs/travis.html
  - wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh;
  - bash miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
  - export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
  - hash -r
  - conda config --set always_yes yes --set changeps1 no
  - conda update -q conda
  # Useful for debugging any issues with conda
  - conda info -a
  # Replace dep1 dep2 ... with your dependencies
  - conda create -q -n test-environment python=$TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION numpy scipy matplotlib pandas cython

  - source activate test-environment

  - python setup.py install

# command to run tests
script:
  - green ...
```

In `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    version="0.0.0",
    name="...",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        ...
        "green>=2.0.7",
        "rpy2>=2.7.7",
    ],
)
```

When Travis CI installs my package I get the following error:

```
Installed /home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tubtrack-0.0.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for tubtrack==0.0.0
Searching for rpy2>=2.7.7
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/
Best match: rpy2 2.7.7
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rpy2/rpy2-2.7.7.tar.gz#md5=be93432426744cdae8a0e5d2b157d371
Processing rpy2-2.7.7.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-CF50ds/rpy2-2.7.7/setup.cfg
Running rpy2-2.7.7/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-CF50ds/rpy2-2.7.7/egg-dist-tmp-TTJjtB
error: Setup script exited with Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command (R) in the PATH.
```

I am wondering if anyone knows how to solve it? I tried to install r in `.travis.yml`:

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - r
```

However, it didn't change the error message...

**EDIT:** In the comments it was pointed that I need to specify at least one source in `addons.apt.sources` for the APT addon to work and R package is named `r-base`. I did the following modifications in `.travis.yml`:

```
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
    - r-packages-precise
    packages:
    - r-base
```

Now it seems that `rpy2` can find `R`, but I am still getting an error when it is imported while the tests are run with `green`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/green-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/green/loader.py", line 212, in loadFromModuleFilename
    __import__(dotted_module)
  File "xxx/xxx/xxx.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .. import tools
  File "xxx/tools.py", line 5, in <module>
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
  File "/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.7.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.7.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import *
ImportError: /home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC
```

However,on my laptop it works fine! So I guess the problem is still that `rpy2` is not installed properly.

Comment: R is not a package. Install from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/). And makes sure it's on your PATH, of course.

Comment: Do you know how to do it automatically with Travis CI?

Comment: Sorta outside my area, but probably something like [this](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r).

Comment: Nope, it is if all project is in R...

Comment: Very Important Note: You need to specify at least one source in `addons.apt.sources` for the APT addon to work (official list [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-source-whitelist/blob/master/ubuntu.json)), in this case - the source (PPA) in which the `r` package is located (`r-packages-precise` if it's in the "default" repo). Also, the R package looks like it's named `r-base`, so make sure this package actually exists.

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь Thank you for your comment. I did what you suggested and updated the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError when using rpy2 with numpy.testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944238/importerror-when-using-rpy2-with-numpy-testing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `ImportError: /home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC` is actually due to readline installed by conda.

This [Github issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/152) has more details about the problem.

The workaround that I have verified to work is to add `import readline`. When my `script` on .travis.yml calls a python script that *only* has

```
import rpy2.robjects
```

I get the same `ImportError: /home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC` error.

When I use the code below, my build goes green.

```
import readline
import rpy2.robjects
```